# Запрет доступа к нескольким файлам

Tags: .htaccess

Банальный вопрос, нужно запретить доступ к нескольким файлам, в примерах везде только один файл.

На один:

```
<Files config.php>
deny from all
</Files>
```

На несколько (типа того):

```
<Files (config.php|cfg.php|incl.php)>
deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте в таком варианте:

```
<Files ~ "^(config|cfg|incl)\.php$">
deny from all
</Files>
```